# Changing button properties in a loop, for example

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to know how it's possible to change button properties by a code when we don't know a button name while writing it.
For example, I have a loop like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
 int buttonName = "button_" + i;
 buttonName.enabled = false;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx) collection of the parent containing the button like this:

```
if(parent.Controls.ContainsKey(buttonName))
{
  Button myButton = (Button)parent.Controls[buttonName];
  myButton.Enabled = false;
}
```

This will need a little extra work if your buttons are not contained within the same parent; ie. some buttons on a Form, some buttons on a Panel contained within that same form.

Comment: Thanks, it works great in the following way `Button myButton = (Button) this.Controls[buttonName];`

Comment: Yes, of course, I forgot the cast, sorry. You could also do `Button myButton = this.Controls[buttonName] as Button;`. If myButton is null after this, then `this.Controls[buttonName]` wasn't a button.